# Combinations of Classes

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

> Hey everyone, I want to combine my classes and get it in
>   only one frame. Now I have 2 classes and I don't know how to group them.
>        The JSlider.

```
    public class JSliderExample extends JFrame {
    JSlider jsHorizontal;
    JTextField jtf1;

    public JSliderExample() {

        jsHorizontal = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 100, 50);


    jtf1 = new JTextField(15);
        jtf1.setEditable(false);
        jtf1.setText("Horizontal value is " + jsHorizontal.getValue());

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panel.add(jsHorizontal);
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panel.add(jtf1);
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);


        getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(300, 400, 400, 300);
        setVisible(true);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    class JSliderHandler implements ChangeListener {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ce) {
            jtf1.setText("value is " + jsHorizontal.getValue());

        }
    }
```

> And there are my buttons

.

```
    public void createGUI() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());


    JButton button2 = new JButton("PLAY");
    button2.setActionCommand("Button PLAY was pressed!");
            panel.add(button2);



    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setColumns(23);
    panel.add(textField);

    ActionListener actionListener = new TestActionListener();

    button1.addActionListener(actionListener);
    button2.addActionListener(actionListener);

    button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            textField.setText(e.getActionCommand());
        }
    });

    getContentPane().add(panel);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 100));
}

  public class TestActionListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        textField.setText(e.getActionCommand());
    }
}
```

> In the end of programm I see 2 frames that consist of 2 classes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            TestFrame frame = new TestFrame();
            frame.pack();
          JSliderExample frame1 = new JSliderExample();

            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

            frame.setVisible(true);





        }

    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to see 2 JFrames, then don't create 2 JFrames. Why not make JPanels with all your classes above and not JFrames, and then in your main method, add your JPanels to the JFrame created within main. Simple.

So for example, instead of having JSliderExample extend JFrame, change it's name to SliderPanel and have it extend JPanel, and likewise with your JButton program. Then your main method could look something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // your JSlider example class **that extends JPanel**
            SliderPanel sliderPanel = new SliderPanel();

            // your JButton example class **that extends JPanel**
            ButtonPanel buttonPanel = new ButtonPanel():

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("My GUI");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(sliderPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
            frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // center GUI if you want
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

    });
}
```